# Can you return the results a query from table and Fields returned in a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following is the results of a query used to Search Columns

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
    [CoreTable] VARCHAR(250),
    [CoreTableDecription] VARCHAR(250),
    [FieldName] VARCHAR(250),
    [cnt] VARCHAR(250)
                 )
declare @Keyword1 VARCHAR(100) = '%Prob%'
declare @Keyword2 VARCHAR(100) = '%Prob%'
--------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO @Temp (CoreTable, CoreTableDecription, FieldName, cnt)
 VALUES 

('PRO','PROTOS_PersonalInformation','AnyCommunicationProblem','1'),
('PRO','PROTOS_PersonalInformation','SightProblems','1'),
('PRO','PROTOS_PersonalInformation','SpeechProblems','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Antenatal_Status','Other_Antenatal_Problems','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Antenatal_Status','Other_Antenatal_Problems_Text','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Details','Neonatal_medical_problems','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Details','Neonatal_medical_problems_Text','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Postnatal','Any_skin_problems_detected','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Postnatal','Any_skin_problems_detected_Bruising','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Postnatal','Any_skin_problems_detected_Naevus','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Postnatal','Any_skin_problems_detected_Rash','1'),
('PRO','PROTOSMODEL_Baby_Postnatal','Any_skin_problems_detected_Text','1')

Select * from @Temp
```

This is great for finding/search and the query used is below

```
declare @Keyword1 VARCHAR(100) = '%Prob%'
declare @Keyword2 VARCHAR(100) = '%Prob%'
select 
    LEFT(o.name,3) CoreTable,
    o.name CoreTableDesc,
    --o.name AS TableName,
    c.name AS FieldName 
    ,COUNT(c.name) cnt
    from sys.columns c
        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
    where c.name LIKE @Keyword1 
    and LEFT(o.name,3)     in ('PRO')
    and c.name LIKE @Keyword2
    GROUP BY c.name, LEFT(o.name,3), o.name
--  order by LEFT(o.name,3), c.name
```

However what I then need to do is run a manual query to determine the values in the columns/tables (see below):

```
select AnyCommunicationProblem, count(*) cnt
from PROTOS_PersonalInformation
GROUP BY AnyCommunicationProblem
```

This returns simplythe rows NULL - 2682, No - 87687, Yes - 135478

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this automatically from the results of the first query which display the Table name and Column names

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL? AFAIK MySQL doesn't support table variables.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` as the syntax is clearly T-SQL

Comment: All I need to do is LEFT JOIN the exact tables from the DW those that are in the examples posted and display the values from the fields also used in the example data. Someone suggested a local variable but unsure what they are yet.

Comment: In the example data 'PROTOS_PersonalInformation' is the table in the DW and 'AnyCommunicationProblem' is a field in the table. I'm after reviewing the data values within that field (grouped) and counted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all the answer was below but I was unsure how to get the count if the data items in

```
DECLARE 
@TABLENAME VARCHAR(255),
@FIELDNAME VARCHAR(255),
@SQL VARCHAR(MAX),
@FieldNamePart1 as varchar(50),
@FieldNamePart2 as varchar(50) 

SET @SQL = ''
SET @FieldNamePart1 = 'Type'
SET @FieldNamePart2 = 'Method'

IF @FieldNamepart2 = ''
       DECLARE CRS CURSOR FOR
       SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE CHARINDEX('PROTOSMODEL',TABLE_NAME) <> 0
              AND CHARINDEX(@FieldNamePart1, COLUMN_NAME) <> 0
 --             AND CHARINDEX('DATE', COLUMN_NAME) = 0
 --             AND CHARINDEX('TIME', COLUMN_NAME) = 0
ELSE
       DECLARE CRS CURSOR FOR
       SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE CHARINDEX('PROTOSMODEL',TABLE_NAME) <> 0
              AND CHARINDEX(@FieldNamePart1, COLUMN_NAME) <> 0
              AND CHARINDEX(@FieldNamePart2, COLUMN_NAME) <> 0
 --             AND CHARINDEX('DATE', COLUMN_NAME) = 0
 --             AND CHARINDEX('TIME', COLUMN_NAME) = 0

OPEN CRS

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @TABLENAME, @FIELDNAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--     SET @SQL = @SQL + CAST('SELECT DISTINCT ''' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(@TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(''' AS PROTOSMODEL_TABLE, ''' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(@FIELDNAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(''' AS PROTOSMODEL_FIELD, ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(@FIELDNAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(' AS FIELD_VALUE FROM ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(@TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(' UNION ALL ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @TABLENAME + ''' AS PROTOSMODEL_TABLE, ''' + @FIELDNAME + ''' AS PROTOSMODEL_FIELD, [' + @FIELDNAME + '] AS FIELD_VALUE FROM ' + @TABLENAME + ' UNION ALL ' 
       FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @TABLENAME, @FIELDNAME
END
CLOSE CRS
DEALLOCATE CRS
SET @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 1, LEN(@SQL) - 10)
EXEC (@SQL)
GO
```